# Does naturality imply independence from choice?

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, model-theory

My question concerns the notion of *naturality* defined in Section 12.3 of Hodge's (longer) *Model Theory*.  See the addenda for the definition.

Hodges proves a result that if an algebraic construction of $B$ from $A$ is not natural, then (if Pincus's transfer principle from ZFA to ZF is applicable) there is a model of ZF with $A$ but with nothing isomorphic to $B$.  An example of such a construction is one of the algebraic closure $B$ from a field $A$.  One is naturally interested in whether its converse obtains in certain circumstances.

The textbook cites two papers by the author himself and Shelah (*Naturality and definability, I* and *II*) which study a similar question but concern global choice principles.  The papers study the converse as well, but I do not believe that they answer the question above.

Is there a paper that address the question whether Hodges's notion of naturality implies that the construction can be done without AC, at least in some cases?

*Addendum.* The following is Hodges's definition of naturality.  The setting is that $B$ has extra nonlogical symbols that $A$ doesn't have, and a unary predicate symbol $P$ is among the extra symbols.  The subset $P^B$ is assumed to induce a substructure of $B$ that happens to be $A$.  Moreover, we assume that every automorphism on $A$ extends to one on $B$, i.e., there is a (set-theoretic) map (called a *section*) $\mathrm{Aut}(A) \to \mathrm{Aut}(B)$.  Under all these assumptions, $B$ is *natural* over $A$ if the section is a group homomorphism, i.e., a *splitting*.

*Addendum II.* I guess that Hodge's notion of naturality translates to that in category theory as follows.  Let $C(M)$ stand for the category of structures isomorphic to a structure $M$ whose morphisms are the isomorphisms.  The construction in question can be thought of as a functor $F : C(A) \to C(B).$  In this setting, the construction is natural in the sense of Hodges iff the inclusion maps $\eta_A : A \to F(A)$ forms a natural transformation from the identity functor on $C(A)$ to $F$.

Comment: It's maybe too long, but also 12.3 in the book is too long for me to search for the definition. How about giving an accurate full reference (page number, etc.)?

Comment: Also if you provide the location of where he has the discussion about Pincus' theorem, it would be great.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The definition is on the very first page of the section.  The discussion about Pincus's theorem is in the very last subsection starting on page 630.  Theorem 12.3.7 on page 631 has the result about ZFA.

Comment: Okay. Having spent some time thinking about this whole thing. It's an interesting question and I will pursue it further. But what is your *actual* question? I mean, Hodges prove that under reasonable conditions, not natural requires choice. And we know that something requiring choice is generally not natural. So natural things, in reasonable scenarios are those things that do not require any choices.

Comment: @AsafKaragila First, I'm not fully convinced why Hodges's naturality is equivalent to everyday naturality (categorical or informal).  For instance, why does the section have to be a group homomorphism?  Second, I have a construction of $B$ from $A$ that actually uses AC but is continuously natural, and I wondered if I circumvent the use of AC.

Comment: The section doesn't have to be a group homomorphism. But it is always injective. So if it is a group homomorphism then it is an embedding, in which case we call it a splitting. It's right there in his definition. What is your construction that uses AC, then? If you want to ask about *that*, just ask about *that*. Don't beat around the bush.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant: why does the section have to be a group hom _in order for the construction to be natural by definition_?

Comment: By which definition? Hodges? Or what?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hodges's definition.

Comment: Well. Hodges says that it's natural if there is a splitting, which is required by definition of a splitting to be a section which is also a group homomorphism. That is the definition that you sent me to read.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, thus my question of how that requirement of the section having to be a group hom is related to the everyday meaning of "natural" as in, e.g., what you wrote "[...] something requiring choice is generally not natural. "

Comment: I have to admit that I never quite understood the notion of "natural" in the general sense that you speak of. If it is a map between functors, what are the functors here? If not, then why is there no simple definition of that anywhere to be found? If the idea is that $\mu\colon A\to B$ is natural when it splits, and whenever $\eta\colon X\to Y$ is epic, and $f\colon A\to X,g\colon B\to Y$ are maps where the diagram commutes, then $h$ splits (or at least if we require $g$ to be epic too), then I will need to think about this some more.

Comment: @Pteromys Do you have any evidence that Hodges's notion of naturality "is meant to be equivalent, at least in spirit, and perhaps technically in some cases, to the notion of the same name in category theory." I don't see any connection to the notion of natural transformation here; I think it's more likely that Hodges just picked a "natural" name, which happens to also have a meaning in category theory.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Not in the textbook itself.  However, Hodges at the end of the section mentions a result that there is no formula of set theory pinning down a unique algebraic closure of a given field because the construction is not "natural."  Now "natural" here refers to the notion defined in the section (because Hodges doesn't talk about other notions of naturality in the textbook), but the papers that he cites and actually contains the said result actually concern category-theoretic naturality.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to take a look at those papers.